# Unable to link css to JSP page

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am not able to link the css to the JSP page -

Project structure:

```
webapp
  resources
    css      
      bootstrap-iso.css
  WEB-INF    
    views
      jsp
        app.jsp
```

The following code in the jsp file works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css"/>
```

However, it doesn't work when I give either of the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap-iso.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap-iso.css"/>
```

I also have resource handler setup in the ApplicationConfig file

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to configure resources with in the `spring-web-config.xml` file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And link the css file with `c:url`:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap-iso.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```